# Menu Lateral do Bootstrap desconfigurado na versão mobile

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, menu

Estou na luta pra fazer um site e apresentá-lo no meu TCC. Separei as seções do site (body, head, cabeçalho, rodapé...) em arquivos isolados para poder mexer com mais facilidade. Tomei o maior cuidado de separar todos os elementos certos em cada arquivo. Eles aparecem no site porque minha página *index.php* tem `include_once()` dessas páginas.

O problema começa aqui: Meu arquivo *menu-lateral.php* está ficando desconfigurado na sua versão mobile. Ele contém os botões de curtir página do Facebook, seguir perfil do Twitter, link para o Flickr e botão de inscrição na página do YouTube.

Aparentemente, o problema está com o botão curtir do Facebook. Sempre que o site está na sua versão desktop, não há problema, fica tudo certo:

<kbd>[image: Versão Desktop: ok]</kbd>

Agora, na versão mobile, ela fica assim (segue foto). O botão está maior do que devia e passando da `div` do menu E acrescentando um espaço enorme para o corpo da página.

<kbd>[image: Versão mobile: errada]</kbd>

Como deveria ficar:

<kbd>[image: Versão mobile: certa]</kbd>

Os outros botões vão ser substituídos por imagens, porém, quero continuar com o botão curtir do Facebook. Quero saber se é possível: **1)** arrumar o problema de espaço na versão mobile; **2)** deixar o tamanho do botão responsivo.

Segue o código do *menu-lateral.php*:

```
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebar">
        <div class="list-group">

            <div class="list-group-item">

            <!-- Facebook -->
            <div class="fb-page jumbo-img" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/ibnovomundo" data-small-header="true" data-adapt-container-width="true" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true" data-show-posts="false" data-layout="box_count">
                <div class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">
                    <blockquote cite="https://www.facebook.com/ibnovomundo">
                        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/ibnovomundo">IBNM - Igreja Batista Novo Mundo</a>
                    </blockquote>
                </div>
            </div>

            </div>

            <center>
            <div class="list-group-item">

            <!-- Twitter -->
            <a class="twitter-follow-button jumbo-img" data-size="large" data-show-count="false" href="https://twitter.com/ibnovomundo">Siga @ibnovomundo no Twitter</a>

            </div>
            <center>

            <div class="list-group-item">

            <!-- YouTube -->
            <div class="g-ytsubscribe list-group-item jumbo-img" data-channel="batistanovomundo2" data-layout="full" data-count="hidden"></div>

            </div>

            <center>
            <div class="list-group-item">
            <!-- Flickr -->
            <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/ibnovomundo2/" title="Veja nossas fotos no Flickr!"><img src="https://s.yimg.com/pw/images/goodies/white-see-my-photos_pt.png" class="jumbo-img" alt="Veja nossas fotos no Flickr!"></a>

            </div>
            </center>

            <center>
            <div class="list-group-item">
            <!-- App -->

            </div>
            </center>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Veja se ajuda http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/add-a-facebook-like-button-to-your-mobile-site.html

Comment: Resumindo a resposta do @AloisoGomes, você só precisa remover a classe `col-xs-6` da `#sidebar`.

Comment: Apenas observando que a solução do @AloisoGomes não é exatamente o que você quer, mas acredito que deva segui-la visto que exibir um menu ao lado do conteúdo em um mobile é extremamente desagradável.

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vamos lá vou tentar te ajudar....

o Bootstrap 3 é rigoroso com o uso correto das classes que determinam o tamanho da coluna da grade, Posso esclarecer dúvidas sobre isso em outra oportunidade, mas a principio faz diferença usar `col-xs-*`, `col-sm-*`, `col-md-*` e `col-lg-*`. Elas se comportarão de maneira diferentes dependendo do tamanho da tela do dispositivo. Vamos a dúvida!

veja só seu código

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebar">
```

como o padrão de colunas do bootstrap é 12 e você usou `.col-xs-6`

isso significa que para mobile `.col-xs-` com o valor 6 vc está dizendo que
METADE da largura total da página será reservado para esse menu... um tamanho desnecessário por isso essa distância grande

normalmente em mobile isso deveria ser exibido abaixo do conteudo como se estivesse sozinho em uma linha para mobile vc consegue esse efeito assim

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3 sidebar-offcanvas">
  <!-- Resto do codigo ... -->
```

Isso fará o menu aparecer abaixo da coluna anterior que deve ser a de conteúdo. Isso é melhor, pois ficará ruim se você tentar deixar lado a lado dificulta a experiencia do usuário e fica esteticamente ruim pois gera rolagem horizontal, algo que vai na contramão de uma pagina que deveria se adaptar a um dispositivo móvel (Responsividade).

Se isso não der certo provavelmente deve ser a estrutura do html que você desenvolveu, os aninhamentos de linhas e colunas contido no seu código. Ficarei contente em ajudar e ensinar o pouco que sei.

Abraço!

Comment: Obrigado amigo, resolveu o problema do espaço ;)

Comment: Por nada cara, adoro ver aqui uma solução para algum problema que tenho, chega uma hora que preciso retribuir. Abraço